# java framework for manipulate audio and video

Tags: java, video-processing

I'm searching a java framework for manipulate audio and video files, I need functions like:

- Split video and audio files
- Get a frame from a video
- Key Frame extraction

I tried Xuggle and I want to know if there are other frameworks.
any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found Xuggler: http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/

Answer (score 1):

Which audio and video format you are dealing with? For MPEG-2, [Project X](http://project-x.sourceforge.net/) may be a solution.

Comment: Thanks!! This project maybe will be very useful for me. Now I'm working with different video format but I think that I'll use MPEG-4 for most of my works. 
In any case, do you know other projects so I can have more choices?